# Place Data in Highchart using json and post url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

Create Line chart with JSON data using  i have a data in json in following format:

**Data**

```
 {"Categoires":["2015-10-31","2015-10-30","2015-11-09","2015-11-08","2015-11-07","2015-11-06","2015-11-10","2015-11-05","2015-11-04","2015-11-12","2015-11-03","2015-11-11"],"Series":[0,2,0,0,0,2,0,2,1,1,4,0]}
```

**Highchart code:**

```
$.post(trendUrl,params,function(data)
        {
            console.log("you are submitting"+data);


        }); 


 $('#trendChart').highcharts({
            title: {

            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {

            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
             gridLineWidth: 1,
            categories: []
        },
        yAxis: {

            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {

        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            color:'#FBA208',
          data: []
        }]
    });
```

Here i would like to plot categories in X and Series in y.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
$(function () {

        data =  {"Categoires":["2015-10-31","2015-10-30","2015-11-09","2015-11-08","2015-11-07","2015-11-06","2015-11-10","2015-11-05","2015-11-04","2015-11-12","2015-11-03","2015-11-11"],"Series":[0,2,0,0,0,2,0,2,1,1,4,0]};
        $('#container').highcharts({
            title: {
                text: 'title',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'subtitle',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: data.Categoires
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'yaxis'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: 'dd'
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'data',
                data: data.Series
            },]
        });
    });
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e2bm7wu8/

Comment: Thanks for your response

Comment: if you dont mind could you proive me with Jsfiddle link it will begreat help

Comment: Thnks its workng fine but i am using  jqurey ajax post and when i uss data varible throwing error

Comment: place the code in the success function of the ajax call

Comment: i hav e achieved could u please help me to place tool tip also what ever categoies only that  date should be in tooltip